# Strange behaviour with indexOf method

Tags: java, string, jakarta-ee, jboss

We have deployed our Java EE web application in jboss 4.0.2 (we are using JDK 1.6.0_18).

In our code we are iterating through the Collection and doing string concatenation of userids in collection (refer below code).

On production server, it behaves inconsistently. The userid (2044157) is not found in final string (refer ServerLog line3). If we restart the production jboss server, then it works perfectly fine and it prints all users correctly in final string log. But the problem again reappears after heavy usage (after 5-6 hours). We are not able to replicate the issue on our QA environment.

When problem happens, Looks like the `indexOf` method incorrectly returns that 2044157 is there in strUsers string (even though 2044157 is not there) and hence it goes into else part and printed it in else part log(refer ServerLog line2 - highlighted in bold font). What could be reason for such inconsistent behavior?

Code:

```
public class UsersEJB implements SessionBean{ 
     private void processSelectionData{ 
     StringBuilder strUsers = new StringBuilder(""); 
     Collection userVoCollection = dc.retProjectOrgUsers(projectID, strDistributionCompID, porjectDataSource); // This is returning List of 626 UserVO 
     if(log.isDebugEnabled()) 
         log.debug("UserList Size="+userVoCollection.size()+",B4 strUsers="+strUsers.toString()); 

     Iterator it = userVoCollection.iterator();

     while(it.hasNext()) { 
         UserVO uVO = (UserVO)it.next(); 
         if(!(strUsers.toString().indexOf("," + uVO.userID.toString() + ",") > -1)) { 
                 strUsers.append(uVO.userID.toString()).append(","); 
                 loopCntPos++; 
         } else { 
                 loopCntNeg++; 
                 if(log.isDebugEnabled()) 
                 log.debug("UserId="+uVO.userID.toString()+",strUsers="+loopCnt+"="+strUsers.toString());
         } 
         loopCnt++; 
     }

     if(log.isDebugEnabled()) 
         log.debug("COMPANIES_ID1 strUsers="+strUsers.toString() + ",### loopCnt="+loopCnt + ",loopCntPos="+loopCntPos + ",loopCntNeg="+loopCntNeg); 

    } 
}
```

ServerLog

> UserList Size=626,B4 strUsers=,1732286,2066065,2096854,1952590,1731333,1732065,1734828,1852547,1732020,1733653,1731278,2079012,1733299,1765873,1733431,1960010,1828681,2047672,1731752,1733172,1784314,1989311,1734795,1732658,1731415,1785285,1785185,1738446,1733139,1732526,1733549,1731078,1804055,1732939,1663167,1732768,1732029,1732504,1989185,1882746,1785428,1731213,1732931,1731296,1733503,1753435,1731667,1936166,1747699,2099764,1482144,1747707,1732953,1771653,1731251,1989303,1755297,1731160,1901283,1782751,1733543,1882693,1733354,1974270,2044300,1732082,1907188,1731872,1955156,1732153,1733260,1731096,1604035,1731914,1731169,1732418,1731240,1989180,1731306,1733533,1882684,1821306,1731178,1731389,1733309,1733104,2078768,1989277,1732542,1733513,1733082,1732630,1733289,1733361,2077522,1733252,1732493,1978847,1733071,
>   UserId=2044157,strUsers=440=,1732286,2066065,2096854,1952590,1731333,1732065,1734828,1852547,1732020,1733653,1731278,2079012,1733299,1765873,1733431,1960010,1828681,2047672,1731752,1733172,1784314,1989311,1734795,1732658,1731415,1785285,1785185,1738446,1733139,1732526,1733549,1731078,1804055,1732939,1663167,1732768,1732029,1732504,1989185,1882746,1785428,1731213,1732931,1731296,1733503,1753435,1731667,1936166,1747699,2099764,1482144,1747707,1732953,1771653,1731251,1989303,1755297,1731160,1901283,1782751,1733543,1882693,1733354,1974270,2044300,1732082,1907188,1731872,1955156,1732153,1733260,1731096,1604035,1731914,1731169,1732418,1731240,1989180,1731306,1733533,1882684,1821306,1731178,1731389,1733309,1733104,2078768,1989277,1732542,1733513,1733082,1732630,1733289,1733361,2077522,1733252,1732493,1978847,1733071,1893797,2137701,2025815,1522850,2027582,1732833,1984513,2037965,1900381,1731514,2044357,2042751,1785407,2118267,2050509,2062445,1934909,1912411,1733673,1731956,1694916,1731951,2048024,1735552,2115155,1732777,2120796,2048007,1845970,1738356,1841988,2101099,2027667,2067876,1734628,1731739,1731893,2051612,1819645,1803654,2037906,1732047,1478544,2073677,2012435,2067977,2073669,1981390,1731124,15916,6766,1978916,1732750,1936298,1891936,1747650,1949484,2101161,1928883,1948164,2013726,1750718,1732164,1733700,1639298,1734968,1732007,1734723,1949403,2137692,1990151,1734617,2101130,1928888,2044163,1732042,1819543,2137672,1735463,1732716,1950975,2025826,1984507,2017645,1372949,1928719,1732684,1952358,1581015,2026878,1731622,1734036,2000528,1734611,2052691,1961286,2107121,1733335,1868846,2000469,1734771,1841953,2118224,2038924,1731609,1735396,2026033,1805573,2107214,1638397,1731502,1731581,2115171,2120903,1892076,2060862,2017603,2002514,1731351,1901274,1760679,1821298,1884485,1777244,1731204,1934917,2000497,1737101,2115043,2121909,2097818,1506144,1953947,1753401,1594875,2135263,1900276,1907168,1851867,1940057,1897000,1765857,2037953,1907085,2037911,2062548,1650062,1801180,1953696,2119602,1605403,1804076,1669286,1844334,1542596,2048001,1938656,1757959,1529666,2070447,1565121,1907065,1944060,2097808,2077490,1843170,1957289,1690800,1823148,1788987,1912477,1738344,1845866,2047996,1962156,1483244,2071932,2127277,1912419,1756748,1999518,1908161,1722312,1548164,1584044,2047896,1856844,1762432,2073439,1861949,1530755,1989292,1852455,2027658,1738380,2067996,1981507,1998543,1958859,1620837,1852555,2012357,1895444,2050380,1789210,1932156,1898948,2046841,2098171,1625335,2138533,2046655,1785464,2105080,2024935,1852446,2073682,1478644,2103660,1751154,1863254,1478332,1849259,1593399,1895334,2075182,2134365,2136657,
>   COMPANIES_ID1 strUsers=,1732286,2066065,2096854,1952590,1731333,1732065,1734828,1852547,1732020,1733653,1731278,2079012,1733299,1765873,1733431,1960010,1828681,2047672,1731752,1733172,1784314,1989311,1734795,1732658,1731415,1785285,1785185,1738446,1733139,1732526,1733549,1731078,1804055,1732939,1663167,1732768,1732029,1732504,1989185,1882746,1785428,1731213,1732931,1731296,1733503,1753435,1731667,1936166,1747699,2099764,1482144,1747707,1732953,1771653,1731251,1989303,1755297,1731160,1901283,1782751,1733543,1882693,1733354,1974270,2044300,1732082,1907188,1731872,1955156,1732153,1733260,1731096,1604035,1731914,1731169,1732418,1731240,1989180,1731306,1733533,1882684,1821306,1731178,1731389,1733309,1733104,2078768,1989277,1732542,1733513,1733082,1732630,1733289,1733361,2077522,1733252,1732493,1978847,1733071,1893797,2137701,2025815,1522850,2027582,1732833,1984513,2037965,1900381,1731514,2044357,2042751,1785407,2118267,2050509,2062445,1934909,1912411,1733673,1731956,1694916,1731951,2048024,1735552,2115155,1732777,2120796,2048007,1845970,1738356,1841988,2101099,2027667,2067876,1734628,1731739,1731893,2051612,1819645,1803654,2037906,1732047,1478544,2073677,2012435,2067977,2073669,1981390,1731124,15916,6766,1978916,1732750,1936298,1891936,1747650,1949484,2101161,1928883,1948164,2013726,1750718,1732164,1733700,1639298,1734968,1732007,1734723,1949403,2137692,1990151,1734617,2101130,1928888,2044163,1732042,1819543,2137672,1735463,1732716,1950975,2025826,1984507,2017645,1372949,1928719,1732684,1952358,1581015,2026878,1731622,1734036,2000528,1734611,2052691,1961286,2107121,1733335,1868846,2000469,1734771,1841953,2118224,2038924,1731609,1735396,2026033,1805573,2107214,1638397,1731502,1731581,2115171,2120903,1892076,2060862,2017603,2002514,1731351,1901274,1760679,1821298,1884485,1777244,1731204,1934917,2000497,1737101,2115043,2121909,2097818,1506144,1953947,1753401,1594875,2135263,1900276,1907168,1851867,1940057,1897000,1765857,2037953,1907085,2037911,2062548,1650062,1801180,1953696,2119602,1605403,1804076,1669286,1844334,1542596,2048001,1938656,1757959,1529666,2070447,1565121,1907065,1944060,2097808,2077490,1843170,1957289,1690800,1823148,1788987,1912477,1738344,1845866,2047996,1962156,1483244,2071932,2127277,1912419,1756748,1999518,1908161,1722312,1548164,1584044,2047896,1856844,1762432,2073439,1861949,1530755,1989292,1852455,2027658,1738380,2067996,1981507,1998543,1958859,1620837,1852555,2012357,1895444,2050380,1789210,1932156,1898948,2046841,2098171,1625335,2138533,2046655,1785464,2105080,2024935,1852446,2073682,1478644,2103660,1751154,1863254,1478332,1849259,1593399,1895334,2075182,2134365,2136657,2041203,2043944,2040358,2093521,1913544,2082455,2024959,2045812,1973980,1494485,1986446,1525605,2046849,1785194,1822210,2053401,1918823,2001794,1785258,2064339,1986338,1710198,1521244,1822292,1931276,2134370,2075073,2134300,2075068,1521210,2131493,1951008,1914649,1774999,1601557,1485584,2078975,1986330,1612190,2064410,2066054,1985760,1685075,1930273,2032161,1955161,,### loopCnt=626,loopCntPos=274,loopCntNeg=352

Comment: I didn't see where the "it" comes from. By the way, you want to have a string of distinct userID separated by comma, so you're suggested to populate the uVO.userID into a Set<?> and a second iteration to build the string via StringBuilder.

Comment: Thanks for your response. "it" is iterator over userVoCollection collection....Now i have edited the the post. We will try your suggestion....But my question is why indexOf method is giving inconsistent result?

Answer (score -1):

As it stands, your search won't pick up the first user as there won't be a preceding comma.  However, I would suggest solving the problem in a far simpler manner, by using a set:

```
public class UsersEJB implements SessionBean
{ 
  private void processSelectionData
  { 
    Collection userVoCollection = dc.retProjectOrgUsers(projectID, strDistributionCompID, porjectDataSource); // This is returning List of 626 UserVO 
    Set<String> usersSet = new HashSet<String>(userVoCollection.size());

    if(log.isDebugEnabled()) 
      log.debug("UserList Size="+userVoCollection.size()+",B4 strUsers="+strUsers.toString()); 

    for (UserVO uVO : userVoCollection)
    {
      if (usersSet.add(uVO.userID.toString())
        loopCntPos++;
      else
      {
        loopCntNeg++;
        if(log.isDebugEnabled())
          log.debug("UserId="+uVO.userID.toString()+",strUsers="+loopCnt+"="+strUsers.toString());
    }


    if(log.isDebugEnabled()) 
      log.debug("COMPANIES_ID1 strUsers=" + usersSet + ",### loopCnt="+loopCnt + ",loopCntPos="+loopCntPos + ",loopCntNeg="+loopCntNeg);     
  } 
}
```